# applications for multiple environment (windows phone 8, windows phone 8.1, windows 8, windows 7, windows xp)

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I have a request for simple application containing few views, no business logic, communication with REST services. The problem lies on multiple environments:

**1.** windows phone 8

**2.** windows phone 8.1

**3.** windows 8

**4.** windows 7

**5.** windows xp

I am concerning WPF application for Windows 8 and and Windows 7, Windows Phone 8 application for Phone 8 and Phone 8.1, for XP (i know it is not supported) separate application.

Do I miss something or there is hidden pitfall ?
It is possible to generalize desktop application for Windows 8, 7 and XP ?

Thanks in advance

**EDIT:**

Finally with help I have solution that fills requirements:

**1.** For Win Phone 8.1 and 8.0 Windows Phone 8.0 application, as it will work on both systems

**2.** For Win 8 and Win 7, WPF application

**3.** For Win XP dedicated application

Looks like a lot of work...

Comment: Poor Windows Vista, that being said I think a WPF application will work on XP,7,8.. if they have the .Net runtime install.  I pretty sure it is 3.0, but it could be 3.5.

Comment: You could use Silverlight out-of-browser app for Windows; will share more code with WP. Not sure how far down-level that works though

Comment: @ChubosaurusSoftware there is .net 4.0 available for Win XP http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/p/dotnet4xp.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit:** As a webapplication is not allowed/possible I'll update my answer but leave the original answer below

If you can install WPF and .NET on Windows XP you may use WPF as Desktop solution.
For Windows Phone you can create a WP8 version. This will then run on WP8, 8.1 and 7.8

Please mind that Windows Phone 8 only supports a subset of WPF so if you like to reuse some XAML you have to consider that and start with Phone.

The codebehind (REST communication) will be C# in both cases.

**Original answer:**

You may create a web application/site.
On Windows Phone you can then create an app which just uses a browser control. It can be distributed in store installed and it's still a website.
On desktop you can either just use the browser or create a winforms app with a browser component.

Comment: unfortunately web browser, hybrid is not an option :/

Comment: Thanks, that was my initial approach, what about windows phone 8.1 as all devices have available upgrade from 8.0 ?. For Windows XP there is problem with .net 4.5 as mentioned in : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/p/dotnet45xp.aspx there is no support from 4.5 :/

Comment: By far not all WP8 are already at WP8.1. I still get reports from my apps that they use WP8. Also it's not a mandatory update, so user may not update at all. And for some phones there might not be an update.

Comment: XP only support .NET 4.0 but you can still run WPF applications. I only used it once and it was .NET 3.5 I think but it works. You may compile shared librarys to a minor .NET version if needed.